# "Peak lemma" and explicit monotone subsequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, closed-form

Looking at the proof of Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem, it found an interesting lemma (called the peak lemma [here](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_Bolzano-Weierstrass)) :

> Every sequence $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ has a monotone subsequence.

Looking at the French Wikipedia article about [subsequence](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sous-suite), it says that the proof of the peak lemma doesn't give an explicit construction of the monotone subsequence. In particular, for the sequence $(\sin(n))_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$, we don't know a closed-form expression for a subsequence $(n_k)_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $(\sin(n_k))_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ is monotone. But there is no reference for this fact. So my question is: do you have any references in this direction?

An additional question is also: do we have a simple (meaning it uses basic functions and/or satisfies a simple recurrence relation) example of a sequence for which we know an explicit (and nontrivial...), ie with a closed-form expression for the subsequence indexes, construction of a monotone subsequence?

Comment: Triviality is in the eye of the beholder, but if you let $x_n$ be the fractional part of $(n/2)(\sqrt5-1)$, then you get a monotone subsequence by taking every other Fibonacci number.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I will be happy to upvote an answer based on your comment (with more details of course). Also, have you heard of any result for the $\sin$ sequence?

Comment: I just wrote a long comment, and it disappeared when I tried to post it. I hope this one survives. Anyway, a result for the sine function takes more knowledge of the continued fraction for $\pi$ than we have (or are ever likely to have). The general question of fractional part of $n\alpha$ for $\alpha$ irrational, I encourage you to read about it in any intro Number Theory text that does diophantine approximation.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: (in case you're interested) A stronger version of the "peak lemma" (first time I've heard this term, by the way) can be proved using Ramsey theory. See this [4 August 2009 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=6805372).

Comment: @Dave, thanks. I was aware of the finite version of this application of Ramsey Theory, which goes by the name of Erdos-Szekeres Theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erdős–Szekeres_theorem